# PHP json_encode() behaves differently with different php versions (integer to string converted)

Tags: php

PHP json_encode() behaves differently with different installations (numeric values to string converted)

Example:

```
$something = array( 
    "value" => "1"
); 

$encoded = json_encode($something);

echo $encoded;
```

Server 1 returns:

```
{"value":"1"}
```

Server 2 returns:
(Note that the option JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK is not set but yet the value is encoded as number)

```
{"value":1}
```

Are there some "global" settings that set JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK automatically?
If yes, where can it be set it and, (bonus question) how retrieve the default options by code?

Comment: Json_encode has **absolutely nothing to do** with your problem. It just encodes the **source array** you are feeding to it

Comment: I make it, you just made this code up for sake of example, but never actually run it on these servers - right?

Comment: It's certainly not a PHP *version* difference, as you can see here the output running on every version of PHP where the function existed: https://3v4l.org/WevSH Either it is some other configuration difference, as you guessed, or there is something else going on in your actual code, and this example isn't reproducible, as the previous commenter guessed.

Comment: I do remember for a while there were multiple versions of the JSON extension around, due to licensing issues (an argument over the right to use software for evil, believe it or not!) Maybe one of the servers has an implementation installed that has a bug in it? It seems unlikely this wouldn't have been picked up when testing the implementation, though.

Comment: Without proof of any kind beyond just sample text, and without any version numbers for us to debug further, there’s really nothing we can do to help this question progress so I’m voting to close. If the OP can provide any of that I’d be glad to vote to reopen.

Comment: The json is returned from the server using $.ajax with method post. I'll try create a MRE to see if the issue exists with a minimal code.